# Can I have k as a random number in random.choices()?

Tags: python, list, random

I want to make a randomized list ,and random.choices does that. An example is

```
 list = [1,2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

numbers = random.choices(list, k=2)

print("2 random numbers", numbers)
```

In this case, it will print 2 random numbers from the list because k is 2 ,but I want k to be a random number in a set range as well ,so a different amount of items on the list would be printed. How do I do that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `randint`

You may use [`random.randint(a, b)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) to generate a number betwwen 0 and the length of the list.

```
values = [1,2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
k = random.randint(0,len(values))
numbers = random.choices(values, k=k)
print(k, "random numbers", numbers)
```

Note that `choices` pick multiple time from the same list, and can so picj multiple times the same, you can result in `6 random numbers [6, 6, 5, 1, 1, 2]`.

---

## `sample`

If you want unique ones, use [`random.sample(population, k)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample)

```
k = random.randint(0,len(values))
numbers = random.sample(values, k=k)
```

---

## *Note*

Don't use built-in names for your variable, such as `list`. Never use existing for a second purpose

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using NumPy for that, it supports such feature right out of the box.

```
import numpy as np

source = [1,2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

numbers = np.random.choice(source, size=2, replace=False)
print("2 random numbers", numbers)
```

This will pick up 2 unique numbers. If you want sampling with replacement, use `replace=True`.

I tend to agree with @azro, never use built-in names for your variable, there are dragons